# QML/QT can't convert QList<QVariantMap> in C++ to an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

QML/QT can't convert QList in C++  to an array of objects in javascript.

```
class ParamListModel:QAbstractListModel
{
     Q_OBJECT
     QList<QVariantMap> paramMapObjList;
     // ...
 public:
     // paramMapObjList can not be converted to an array 
     // of objects in  javascript 
     // so I have to use this method:
     // the returned QVariantMap will be converted to javascript object
     // by QML automatically.
     Q_INVOKABLE QVariantMap getParamObj(int index); 
     // ...
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if QML understands QList of QVariantMap, but indeed it understands QVariant. I normally nest QVariantMap data like this, to use it in ListView items:

```
QVariant MyClass::myListModel()
{
    QVariantList vList;

    for(Group *grp : groups())
    {
        QVariantMap vMap;
        vMap.insert("mIcon", "qrc:/icon.svg");
        vMap.insert("mLabel", grp->name());
        vMap.insert("mValue", grp->id());
        vList.append(vMap);
    }

    return QVariant::fromValue(vList);
}
```

And then you can have a Q_PROPERTY like this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariant myListModel READ myListModel NOTIFY myListModelChanged)
```

Comment: You could also consider implementing a list model, where each entry presents the values of what you currently transport as a `QVariantMap`, but with more control on change notification

Comment: FWIW, you can just wrap `QVariantMap` inside a `QVariantMap`.